# Using Lambda to search for an array of strings

Tags: c#, lambda

I've got a generic list (vwsearch) with a string field (ProductSearch) in it . And an array of strings (stringarray)

How would I search through my list for the records where the string field equals or contains all of the string values in the array.
I've got the following code which returns the records where the ProductSearch field contains any of the strings values in the array.

```
vwsearch = vwsearch.Where(v=>v.ProductSearch.Contains(stringarray.Last()))
```

Comment: Your code is VB.Net, why your question is tagged with C#, Also your current code doesn't return records where "`ProductSearch` field contains any of the string values in array", instead it would return only those records where `ProductSearch` Contains last item from the array.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
vwsearch = vwsearch.Where(v => stringarray.All(s => v.ProductSearch.Contains(s)))
```